# Create 3D grid in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop, logic

I want to create a 3D grid with PHP.

I am trying to populate it according to the following logic:

> The desired output is 10x10x10 = 1000 entries.

However, I am only getting 30 entries. 
How do I make this iterate back so that at xposition 0, yposition and zposition each count to 10 before xposition increments to 1 and then yposition and zposition count to 10 and so on? Thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP Logic Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing PHP counting</h1>

</body>
</html>

<?php

$width = 10;
$length = 10;
$height = 10;
$size = 1;

$xposition = 0;
$yposition = 0;
$zposition = 0;

$grid = [];
$grid_index = 0;

while ($xposition < $length) {

    $grid[$grid_index] = $xposition." ".$yposition." ". $zposition. "<br />"; 
    echo $grid[$grid_index]; 
    $xposition = $xposition + $size;
    $grid_index++;

    while ($yposition < $width) {

        $grid[$grid_index] = $xposition." ".$yposition." ". $zposition. "<br />"; 
        echo $grid[$grid_index]; 
        $yposition = $yposition + $size;
        $grid_index++;

        while ($zposition < $height) {

            $grid[$grid_index] = $xposition." ".$yposition." ". $zposition. "<br />"; 
            echo $grid[$grid_index]; 
            $zposition = $zposition + $size;
            $grid_index++;
        }

    }

}

echo $grid_index;

?>
```

Currently this is my output:

```
0 0 0
1 0 0
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 1 4
1 1 5
1 1 6
1 1 7
1 1 8
1 1 9
1 1 10
1 2 10
1 3 10
1 4 10
1 5 10
1 6 10
1 7 10
1 8 10
1 9 10
1 10 10
2 10 10
3 10 10
4 10 10
5 10 10
6 10 10
7 10 10
8 10 10
9 10 10
30
```

Comment: You need to reset $zposition and $yposition to 0 in the outer while loops.

Comment: Thanks.  That set me on the path to solve it.